# Prove that $(C[0,1], d_1)$ is not a complete metric space with this especific example

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am completely stuck on this problem: $C[0,1] = \{f: f\text{ is continuous function on } [0,1] \}$ with metric $d_1$ defined as follows:

$d_1(f,g) = \int_{0}^{1} |f(x) - g(x)|dx $.

Let the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n =1}^{\infty}\subseteq C[0,1]$ be defined as follows:

$
   f_n(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
     min\{1, {1\over 2}-n(x -{1\over 2} )\} & \quad \text{ $x\in [0, 1/2]$}\\
     max\{0, {1\over 2}-n(x -{1\over 2} )\} & \quad \text{$x\in [1/2, 1]$}\\
  \
   \end{array} \right.
 $
Using this function to show that $C[0,1]$ is not complete.

I need help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Estimate $d_1(f_m,f_n)$ for $0<m<n$ as follows: For any $n>0$ let $p(n)=(1-1/n)/2$ and $q(n)=(1+1/n)/2$.  For $0<m<n$ we have $0\le p(m)<p(n)<q(n)<q(m) \le 1$ .We have $$f_m(x)=f_n(x)=1$$ for $x \in [0,p(m)]$ and $$f_m(x)=f_n(x)=0$$ for $y \in [q(m),1]$.Therefore $$d_1(f_m,f_n)=\int_{p(m)}^{q(m)} |f_m(x)-f_n(x)| dx$$. A crude upper bound for $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|$ for $ x \in [p(m).q(m)]$ is $$|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\leq |f_m(x)|+|f_n(x)|\le 2$$. Therefore $$d_1(f_m,f_n) \leq \int_{p(m)}^{q(m)} 2 dz =2(q(m)-p(m)=2/m.$$ So $(f_n)_{n \in N}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Now consider a function $g$  on $[0,1]$ where $g(x)=1$ when  $x \in[0,1/2)$ and $g(x)=0$ when $x \in (1/,1]$. (The value of $g(1/2)$ is irrelevant.) Observe that for any $h \in C[0,1]$ there exists  $x \in (0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1)$ where $h(x) \ne g(x)$  .(Else $h$ is discontinuous at the point $1/2$).So there exists $e>0$ such that  $$(x-e,x+e) \subset (0,1/2) \cap (1/2,1)$$and $$|g(y)-h(y)|> |g(x)-h(x)|/2 $$for all $y \in (x-e,x+e)$.BUT for all but finitely many $ n $ we have : $ f_n(y)=g(y)$ for all $y \in (x-e,x+e)$ because $$(x-e,x+e)\cap [p(n),q(n)]=\phi$$ for all but finitely many  $n$.Therefore  for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $$d_1(f_n,h) > \int_{x-e}^{x+e} |g(y)-h(y)| dy > (2 e) (|g(x)-h(x)|/2).$$  So  any $h \in C[0,1]$ is NOT the limit of  $(f_n)_{n \in N}$. Note that we didn't need an exact value for $d_1(f_m,f_n)$ ,which simplified the calc's.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the idea is that you start with functions that look like a flat line, a continuous elevation (or decline) and then a flat line.  You then make the elevation (or decline) more and more steep until it disappears and you are left with a noncontinuous step function.

EDIT:  The point is that in a complete space every Cauchy sequence is convergent.  It's trivial to see that your sequence is Cauchy, but by the above argument it converges to a not continuous function (hence it does not converge in the set of continuous functions) and hence the space $(C[0,1],d_1)$ is not complete.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see where in your answer you use the specified distance function.  The OP has to show two things: 1) $f_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the distance metric, and 2) there does not exist $f \in C([0,1])$ such that $f_{n} \to f$ under the specified distance metric.